# How to find the site that crashes the server?

Tags: server, apache2, mysql

Probably 1 out of 100 sites crashes the VPS every few days.
Apache connections go to few hundreds and mysql requests to few millions. That causes the CPU to be at 100%+ permanently and making the server completely unusable.
Restart fixes the situation for few days.
How to find the evil one?

I've god mod_status with extendedstatus ON but still, it just shows the few recent requests. Not sure how to use that to narrow it down among 100 sites.

The rest of the time the server is using 20-30% of the resources so it's not overloaded with sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't known lot about your server configuration but I will try to help.

First start `iptables` and do not allow to attack your server

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m limit --limit 25/minute --limit-burst 100 -j ACCEPT
```

After that i think that `logrotate` can help us to find site with highest impact.

Install `logrotate`

```
sudo apt-get install logrotate
```

To verify that logrotate was successfully installed, run this in the command prompt.

```
logrotate
```

Configurations and default options for the `logrotate` utility are present in:

```
/etc/logrotate.conf
```

Some of the important configuration settings are : rotation-interval, log-file-size, rotation-count and compression.

Application-specific log file information (to override the defaults) are kept at:

```
/etc/logrotate.d/
```

My idea is to monitor http access file. Site with more access must have bigger access log. `Logrotate` and `cron` will watch for us on this and send you mail about problem ...

Edit `logrotate.conf` and add some code

`sudo nano /etc/logrotate.conf`

```
/path_to_apache_logs/*.log {
    size 1M
    dateext
    postrotate
      /usr/bin/killall -HUP httpd
      ls -ltr /path_to_apache_logs/ | mail -s "$HOSTNAME: Apache restarted and log files rotated" name@domain.com
    endscript
}
```

You must customise

`size` - size of log file, change based on your needs
`path_to_apache_logs` - change path based on log path in `vhost.conf`

More about customization of `logrotate.conf` you can find [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/logrotate-examples/)

Setup `cron` to run `logrotate` on every 5 min

```
*/5  *  *  *  *   root    /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf
```

When you are on "attack" you access log will growth fast. `Cron` will run `logrotate` to check log file size and if file size is XX will rotate log, restart atache and send you mail.

Because every virtual host have own access file you will known witch site is server "killer"